# Android Layout; Image takes entire screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to fill an activity with two views, an `ImageView` on the left side, and a `TextView` on the right. The image should be sized so as to fill the entire vertical space. The text should occupy whatever space is left over. After watching a few tutorials, it seems like what I need is a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation, and for the `TextView`'s `layout_weight` property to be a positive integer.

This is what I have so far:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/charsheet" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ipsum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/ipsum" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is, however, that the image, creates white space to the left and right which fills the entire screen. There is no room left for the `TextView`.

[image]

I also tried using a `RelativeLayout` with the `ImageView`'s `toStartOf` property set to the id of the `TextView`, but then the text fills the entire screen instead.

I wouldn't have thought this would be such a complicated thing to do, when I set out to make this activity, but here we are. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want the image to be cropped to fit or resize to fit?

Comment: Resized, I think. I want to see the whole image, just minus the white space that is being added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the thing you're missing is adjustViewBounds on the ImageView.  Try like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/doug"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ipsum"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ipsum"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Without adjustImageBounds, ImageView takes up more space than it needs to display the image.

The above layout creates a preview in Android Studio that looks like this for me:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work in Android studio 3.0. I just tried it. The background is black and the textview is much smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Move `android:layout_weight="1"` to the ImageView, and in the TextView make the weight 0. Note: You need to set the layout_width of the ImageView to 0px.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ipsum"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="ipsum" />
```

Comment: That causes the text to completely fill the screen, leaving the image hidden

Comment: I forgot the layout_width:0px, try now

Comment: Now the image doesn't scale, and the entire screen is filled with part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the ImageView scaleType, like:

```
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Comment: That does not appear to have any effect